# How to paste copied data to the next empty cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to paste the copied data to the next empty cell.

I'm already done with my codes on copying the data. And I am getting into trouble in pasting it. Below is my code:

```
Dim eRow As Long
 Workbooks("Daily Task Tracker - March 2015.xlsx").Activate
 Worksheets("Tasks").Activate
 Sheets("Tasks").Select
 eRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
 Cells(eRow, "A:G").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Could someone help me on finding the error on my syntax?

Code from OP's comment:

```
'Copy Data
Sheets("Daily Tasks Tracker").Select
Range("D8").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: Where is the source of the copy? You run through two worksheets without doing anything then paste into a third but there is no mention of where the data was copied from.

Comment: This is how I copy the data from the source.

    `'Copy Data
    Sheets("Daily Tasks Tracker").Select
    Range("D8").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy`

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, you only need to specify the top-left cell if you are pasting a block of data copied from a range of cells.

```
Dim eRow As Long
with Sheets("Tasks")
    eRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) + 1
    .Cells(eRow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
end with
```

Alternate without `Select`:

It is often best to find the last used cell by looking from the bottom up then advancing down one cell to the first unused one. Looking from the top down or counting cells with values may run into a blank cell which will produce false results.

```
Dim w As Long, h As Long
With Sheets("Daily Tasks Tracker")
    'D9 is Range("D8").Offset(1, 0).Select
    w = .Range(.Range("D9"), .Range("D9").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count
    h = .Range(.Range("D9"), .Range("D9").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
    .Range("D9").Resize(h, w).Copy _
      Destination:=Sheets("Tasks").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With
```

If you are pasting `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`, you are pretty much just performing a standard copy and paste. This is easier to code and you do not have to add an `Application.CutCopyMode = False` to halt the copy mode.

Comment: @Jeeped- `WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) + 1` -will not guarantee the last row in column A,
Would it not be better to use
 `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row+1`?

Comment: @Davesexcel - Yes, I'm preparing an alternate without `.Select` but I had to wait until I got the code from the original copy.